# My second if and else if statement produces the wrong answer

Tags: java, if-statement

For some reason I cant get the right code for 4 stand tickets which equates to 100 (without oap/child discount and over 5 ticket discount with the cost of 4 dinners bringing the total to 180 which is then multiplied by 1.21 to equal 217.9. If I put a System.out.println(vatTotalNoAgeLess5); outside the second if block it will print 217.8 yet if I dont it gives me the cost of 4 oap/child tickets + 4 dinners * 1.21 which is 195.65.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //data dictionary
    double standT, terraceT, grossTick, handlingFee, ticketDiscount, flatFee, totalCost, agetick, over5tick,
    vatTotal, totaltick, dinnerPrice, dinnerTotal, vatTotalForAge, vatTotalNoAgeLess5;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //gathering basic inputs from user  
    System.out.println("Input your name ");
    String name = in.next();
    System.out.println("Input your mobile number ");
    String mobile = in.next();
    System.out.println("How many stand tickets do you want? ");
    int standTick = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many terrace tickets do you want? ");
    int terraceTick = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("OAP/Student tickets? y/n");
    String ageDiscount = in.next();
    //basic fees as variables
    standT = 25 * standTick;
    terraceT = 20 * terraceTick;
    handlingFee = 7.50;
    dinnerPrice = 20;

    //defining the total cost variables
    grossTick = terraceT + standT;

    if(ageDiscount.equals("Y") || ageDiscount.equals("y"))
    {
        //System.out.println(grossTick);
        agetick = grossTick * 0.85;
        System.out.println("Before vat the total is " + agetick);
    }
    else if (ageDiscount.equals("N") || ageDiscount.equals("n"))
    {
        System.out.println("Before vat the total is " + grossTick);
    }
    else if(standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        over5tick = grossTick * 0.82;
        System.out.println("Before vat the total is " + over5tick);
    }
    else if (standTick + terraceTick < 5 )
    {
        System.out.println("Before vat the total is " + grossTick);
    }
    else if (ageDiscount.equals("Yes") || ageDiscount.equals("yes")  && standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        over5tick = grossTick * 0.82;
        System.out.println("Before vat the total is " + over5tick);
    }


    System.out.println("Will you be having dinner? y/n ");
    String havingDinner = in.next();

    if(havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y") || ageDiscount.equals("Y") || ageDiscount.equals("y"))
    {
        agetick = (grossTick * 0.85);
        dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
        vatTotalForAge = ((dinnerTotal + agetick) * 1.21);
        System.out.println(vatTotalForAge);
    }
    else if (havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")||ageDiscount.equals("N") || ageDiscount.equals("n"))
    {
        dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
        vatTotalNoAgeLess5 = ((dinnerTotal + grossTick) * 1.21);
        System.out.println(vatTotalNoAgeLess5);
    }



    /*
    if(havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")|| ageDiscount.equals("Y") || ageDiscount.equals("y")) 
    {
        agetick = (grossTick * 0.85);
        dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
        vatTotalForAge = ((dinnerTotal + agetick) * 1.21);
        System.out.println(vatTotalForAge);
    }

    else if(havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y") || ageDiscount.equals("N") || ageDiscount.equals("n"))
    {
        dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
        vatTotalNoAgeLess5 = ((dinnerTotal + grossTick) * 1.21);
        System.out.println("is");

    }
    dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
    vatTotalNoAgeLess5 = ((dinnerTotal + grossTick) * 1.21);
    System.out.println(vatTotalNoAgeLess5);



    /*
    if( dinner > 0 || ageDiscount.equals("Yes") || ageDiscount.equals("yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Total of dinner and vat is " +(( agetick + dinner)*1.21));
    }
    else if (dinner > 0||ageDiscount.equals("No") || ageDiscount.equals("no"))
    {
    System.out.println("Total of dinner and vat is " + ((grossTick + dinner)*1.21));
    }
    else if(dinner > 0||standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Total of dinner and vat is " + (over5tick*1.21 + dinner));
    }
    else if (dinner > 0 ||standTick + terraceTick < 5 )
    {
        System.out.println("Total of dinner and vat is " + ((grossTick*1.21) + dinner));
    }
    else if (dinner > 0||ageDiscount.equals("Yes") || ageDiscount.equals("yes")  && standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Total of dinner and vat is " + (over5tick*1.21 + dinner));
    }
    else if (dinner < 1 || ageDiscount.equals("No") || ageDiscount.equals("no"))
    {
    System.out.println("Total including and vat is " + grossTick*1.21);
    }
    else if(dinner < 1 ||standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Total including and vat is " + over5tick*1.21);
    }
    else if (dinner < 1 ||standTick + terraceTick < 5 )
    {
        System.out.println("Total including and vat is " + grossTick*1.21);
    }
    else if (dinner < 1 || ageDiscount.equals("Yes") || ageDiscount.equals("yes")  && standTick + terraceTick >= 5)
    {
        System.out.println("Total including and vat is " + over5tick*1.21 );
    }
    */
}
```

}

Comment: not directly related to the question, but you might consider using case statements for readability: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Also: `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: use BigDecimal double have troubles in calculating

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're asking about when you say "the second if and else if statement", but checking `havingDinner` in `else if (havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")||  ` is redundant, because if these are true, the preceding `if` condition would also be true.

Comment: Free tip: wrong if-statements

Comment: Is the commented-out part relevant to the question?  If not, could you perhaps remove it?

Comment: This code is a complete mess. Please rethink your logic! For example, the "over 5 tickets discount" is only applied if the answer to "OAP/Student tickets? y/n" is neither `y` nor `n`. And if the answer to "Will you be having dinner? y/n" is `y` then you calculate `agetick = (grossTick * 0.85);` ??

Comment: @AndyTurner I suspect there was supposed to be an AND somewhere in each of those two conditions.  Like `((A || B) && (C || D))` but it's kind of hard to tell from the problem statement.

Comment: Your 5th `if` never runs, because the 3rd and 4th `if` cover all cases between them.

Comment: [I downvoted because there appears to have been no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Please see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some general debugging advice.

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of thing that you could solve in 30 seconds by stepping through with a debugger.  Cloudsourcing debugging to the Stack Overflow community isn't always very successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BigDecimal** use example

```
vatTotalNoAgeLess5 = BigDecimal.valueOf(dinnerTotal).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(grossTick)).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.21)).doubleValue();
```

**Example** if statement

```
if ((havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")) && (ageDiscount.equals("Y") || ageDiscount.equals("y"))) {
    agetick = (grossTick * 0.85);
    dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
    vatTotalForAge = ((dinnerTotal + agetick) * 1.21);
    System.out.println(vatTotalForAge);
} else if ((havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")) && (ageDiscount.equals("N") || ageDiscount.equals("n"))) {
    dinnerTotal = dinnerPrice * (standTick + terraceTick);
    vatTotalNoAgeLess5 = ((dinnerTotal + grossTick) * 1.21);
    System.out.println(vatTotalNoAgeLess5);
}
```

Comment: When I say no to dinner it gives me the 217 but when I say yes it says 195. Still though its getting there, thanks

Comment: check your if statement and group your condition ((havingDinner.equals("Y") || havingDinner.equals("y")) && (ageDiscount.equals("Y") || ageDiscount.equals("y")))